# JFXPanel setScene freezing with java 11

Tags: java, windows, java-11, openjfx

I want to integrate openjfx into my Java 11 code. Using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 on Windows 10, I created a test project and tried out below code

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class Java11FXTestApplication {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFXPanel dummyPanel;
        TabPane dummyTabPane;
        Scene dummyScene;
        System.out.println("Creating JFX Panel");
        dummyPanel = new JFXPanel();
        System.out.println("Creating  TabPane");
        dummyTabPane = new TabPane();
        System.out.println("Creating  Scene");
        dummyScene = new Scene(dummyTabPane);
        System.out.println("Setting  Scene");
        dummyPanel.setScene(dummyScene); //Freezing here
        System.out.println("Scene Created");
    }
}
```

this code is freezing in setScene() method call. 
I tried debugging it and found that it the code wait indefinitely in secondaryLoop.enter() call in JFXPanel.setScene method. any Idea why?

> This code works fine in JDK-8 but not working with java-11.0.1.

I am getting nowhere with this issue, kind of stuck at the Java11 JavaFX problem. Is there something wrong with the code? or any reported issue with javafx for java11

Comment: which version of [openjfx](https://openjfx.io/) are you using? which module/package exports the class `import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;`?

Comment: using openjfx-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk

Comment: @nullpointer `JFXPanel` is exported by the `javafx.swing` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the `Scene` on the main thread. From the documentation of [`JFXPanel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) (**emphasis** mine):

> There are some restrictions related to `JFXPanel`. As a Swing component, it should only be accessed from the event dispatch thread, except **the `setScene(javafx.scene.Scene)` method, which can be called either on the event dispatch thread or on the JavaFX application thread.**

Wrap `setScene` in a `Platform.runLater` call (or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`).

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    dummyPanel.setScene(dummyScene);
    System.out.println("Scene Created");
});
```

Note that, with your current code, once `main` returns the JVM will continue to run. Creating a `JFXPanel` initializes the JavaFX runtime which won't exit until that last window is closed (only when `Platform.isImplicitExit` is `true`) or `Platform.exit` is called. Since your code does neither, the JavaFX runtime will keep running.

---

The documentation of `JFXPanel` also gives an example of how it expects to be used (note nearly everything happens on either the *Event Dispatch Thread* or *JavaFX Application Thread*):

> Here is a typical pattern how `JFXPanel` can used:
>
> ```
>  public class Test {
>
>      private static void initAndShowGUI() {
>          // This method is invoked on Swing thread
>          JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
>          final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
>          frame.add(fxPanel);
>          frame.setVisible(true);
>
>          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
>              @Override
>              public void run() {
>                  initFX(fxPanel);
>              }
>          });
>      }
>
>      private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
>          // This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
>          Scene scene = createScene();
>          fxPanel.setScene(scene);
>      }
>
>      public static void main(String[] args) {
>          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>              @Override
>              public void run() {
>                  initAndShowGUI();
>              }
>          });
>      }
>  }
> ```

Comment: The solution worked perfectly and it is well explained too. I wonder why the same code was working in java-8 and not in java-11? Is there substantial changes in how JFX works from java-8-fx to openjfx?

Comment: I suspect some decent changes occurred while modularizing the JDK and JavaFX libraries for Java 9. With the separation of JavaFX 11 from the JDK they've also been removing dependencies on internal Swing code—preferring public API instead. So while I don't know the details I'd be surprised if the implementation didn't change at least somewhat. Also, the documentation for `JFXPanel` is the same in JavaFX 8 which means you were likely just getting lucky (or inadvertently relying on some implementation detail).

Comment: It seems that only `Platform.runLater` works in Java 11, and not `SwingUtilities.invokeLater ` where `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` also worked in Java 8.

Comment: @StevenSpungin If that's true then it's a bug, at least according to the documentation.